# sending print job from python to google cloud print

Tags: python, linux, google-api, python-requests, httprequest

**The problem**

I want to send a print job from a python script to a printer that is registered in 'Google Cloud Print'.

**What I think I need for this**

- google account
- google cloud api registration: client-id, client-secret (to gain my access token)
- access token

  I got my access token by using this tutorial:

https://github.com/burnash/gspread/wiki/How-to-get-OAuth-access-token-in-console%3F

**What I've tried so far**

Since Bradley Ayers wrote exactly for this purpose a python-library called cloudprinting (https://github.com/bradleyayers/cloudprinting) the following script is meant to deal with my print job:

```
from cloudprinting import *

access_token = 'xyz_token_xyz' # here my personal access token is stated

auth = OAuth2(access_token, token_type="Bearer")

r = submit_job(printer="e506d12-dbe0-54d3-7392-fd69d45ff2fc", content="some_pdf_in_local_directory.pdf", auth=auth)
```

Although the script finishes without error messages it doesn't work - which means there is no print job at the end.

So I tried to come up with my own attempt of a ***http post to Google Cloud Print***:

```
import requests
import json

access_token = 'xyz_acces_token_xyz' # here my personal access token is stated
printer =  "e506d12-dbe0-54d3-7392-fd69d45ff2fc" # random printer_id 
capabilities = [{}]

data = {"printerid": printer,
    "title": "name",
    "contentType": "pdf",
    "capabilities": json.dumps({"capabilities": capabilities})}

post_request = requests.post('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', headers={'Authorization': access_token},data=data,files='some_pdf_in_local_directory.pdf')

print (post_request.text)
```

Clearly the above requests.post() parameters aren't correct. Which parameters do I need stated in what way?
Or more specifically:

1. Is ''https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit' the correct endpoint?
2. What is the correct way of authentication?
3. What argument-value-pairs does the variable 'data' need ?

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if anyone still interested using the tutorial to get the access token, i could also get the refresh token with print(credentials.refresh_token), with that I wrote a class that prints, and refresh the token when needed.
i could successfully print from python in my cloud printer, also you have to change the scope to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint"

hope it helps

```
class CloudPrint():
    def __init__(self,client_id=None, client_secret=None, access_token = None, refresh_token = None):
            self.client_id = client_id
            self.client_secret= client_secret
            self.access_token = access_token
            self.refresh_token = refresh_token
            self.deadline = time.time()-1
        self.api_url ='https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit'

    def safe_check(self):
        if time.time()>float(self.deadline):
            self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        print('google refreshing')
        token = requests.post(
                'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                data={
                    'client_id': self.client_id,
                    'client_secret': self.client_secret,
                    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
                    'refresh_token': self.refresh_token,
                }
            )
        self.access_token = token.json()['access_token']
        self.deadline = self.deadline + token.json()['expires_in']
        print('new deadline ', self.deadline)

    def print(self, file, title, printerids):
            self.safe_check()
            body = {"printerid":printerids,
            "title":[title],
            "ticket":"{\r\n  \"version\": \"1.0\",\r\n  \"print\": {}\r\n}",
            }
            files = {'content': open(file,'rb')}

            headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer "+str(self.access_token)}
            print(headers)
            r = requests.post(self.api_url, data=body, files=files, headers=headers)
            print(r.url)
            print(r.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gcp = CloudPrint(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN)
    gcp.print('prueba.txt', 'prueba', PRINTER_ID_DEB)
```

Comment: Only one thing. The `print` method needs to be replaced with something else, i.e.`gcp_print`. `print` is a reserved keyword in python.